# PowerShell New-Item will create the directory where the script is and not in the path specified

Tags: powershell, directory, new-item

I am writing a PowerShell script and I need to create a directory in `C:\Users`

My script is located on the desktop.

My line of script to create the directory is this:

```
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Force -Path "C:Users\username\scripts\documents"
```

It instead creates the directory:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop\Users\username\scripts\documents
```

How can I make the new directory directly in `C:\Users`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing a backslash `\` after the path root (the drive letter):

```
New-Item -ItemType "directory" -Force -Path "C:\Users\username\scripts\documents"
```

See also: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.ispathrooted?view=net-5.0

> A **rooted path** is file path that is fixed to a specific drive or UNC
> path; it contrasts with a path that is relative to the current drive
> or working directory. For example, on Windows systems, a rooted path
> begins with a backslash (for example, `\Documents`) or a drive letter
> and colon (for example, `C:Documents`).
>
> Note that rooted paths can be either absolute (that is, fully
> qualified) or relative. An absolute rooted path is a fully qualified
> path from the root of a drive to a specific directory. A relative
> rooted path specifies a drive, but its fully qualified path is
> resolved against the current directory. The following example
> illustrates the difference.

```
$relative1 = "C:Documents"
$relative2 = "\Documents"
$absolute = "C:\Documents"

foreach ($p in $relative1,$relative2,$absolute) {
    "'$p' is Rooted: {0}" -f [System.IO.Path]::IsPathRooted($p)
    "Full path of '$p' is: {0}" -f [System.IO.Path]::GetFullPath($p)
}
```

(I did not include the `[System.IO.Path]::IsPathFullyQualified()` call in the linked example, because it is not included in Windows PowerShell 5.1)